# how to implement pay pal in cocoa objective C application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, paypal

I want to implement paypal in my application and it is purely objective C based.

How should I do that? I searched a lot but could not get any proper guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paypal has a pretty extensive SOAP API available for external use.  Cocoa doesn't have the greatest support for SOAP, but you could probably get something to work via those APIs.

Comment: @ashish They're behind a login page, but this is the link: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference

Comment: thanks dave I went thr that and trying to create a webservice call to paypal sandbox...still struggling in doing that

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by creating a button in Paypal. Once the button is created, Paypal gives a HTML link for that button for use in emails. Once that has been done, the link can be opened using a combination of NSURL and [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL: ].

Comment: Login to Paypal. 
Click on Merchant Services at the centre of the row of tabs near the top.
In the useful links section under Website Payments Standard there is a link titled Buy Now Buttons. Click on that and you should be fine.

Comment: but how will you come to know that user has done with transaction by creating a button in paypal